# How to turn do make these function in to chaining function?

Tags: javascript, method-chaining

Am trying to use the chaining method but am not sure how to that yet. I have researched online and still haven't found any success any help will be appreciated.

// The URL root if user searches by city
const API_ROOT_CITY = "http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=";

// Parameters for geonames
const API_ROOT_PARAMS = "&maxRows=1"

// API KEY for geonames
const API_KEY = `&username=kamara.moses`;

// WeatherBit URL
const API_ROOT_BIT = "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?"

```
// Parameters for weatherbit
const API_BIT_PARAMS = "&city="

// API KEY for weatherbit
const API_BIT_KEY = "&key=cda6df51d9a24b8c9d54b830f4eadb51"

// PixaBay URL
const API_ROOT_PIXA = "https://pixabay.com/api/?"

// API KEY for pixabay
const API_PIXA_KEY = "key=19853981-85155ca595da994be43f034e6"

// Parameters for pixabay
const API_PIXA_PARAMS = "&q="

// Type of image from pixabay
const API_PIXA_IMAGE = "&image_type=photo"

// Main function of the program
// Grabs the user"s input, then forms URL, calls API, POSTS and updates UI
function clickRespond() {

   // Grab user"s input
    const cityInput = document.getElementById("city");
    
   

    // Read values of zip and city
    const city = cityInput.value;
    

    // Form URL based on zip or city search
    // (zip takes precendence if both were entered)
    let url;
    let bitURL;
    let pixaURL;
  
    if (city) {
        url = API_ROOT_CITY + city + API_ROOT_PARAMS + API_KEY;
        bitURL = API_ROOT_BIT + API_BIT_PARAMS + city + API_BIT_KEY;
        pixaURL = API_ROOT_PIXA + API_PIXA_KEY + API_PIXA_PARAMS + API_PIXA_IMAGE;
    }

    // Call the API
    getGeo(url)
    

        // Prepares data for POST, calls the POST
        .then(function (response) { // CHANGE: call it response
            console.log(response)
            const errorMessage = document.getElementById("error");
            if (response.status == "200") { // CHANGE: check the status
                errorMessage.classList.add("hide");
                const city = response.geoNames.geonames[0].name; // Change

                postJournal("/add", { city }) ;
                // Calls to update the site with latest entry
                updateUI();

            } else {
                console.log("Bad data entered");
                errorMessage.classList.remove("hide");
                return;
            }
        })

        getWeather(bitURL)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response)
            const errorMessage = document.getElementById("error");
            if (response.status == "200") {
                errorMessage.classList.add("hide");
                const icon = response.weatherBit.data[0].weather.icon;
                const description = response.weatherBit.data[0].weather.description
                const newDate = dateTime();
                const date = newDate;
                const highTemp = response.weatherBit.data[0].high_temp;
                const lowTemp = response.weatherBit.data[0].low_temp
                postJournal("/add", { icon: icon, description: description, date: date, highTemp: highTemp, lowTemp: lowTemp  });

                // Calls to update the site with latest entry
                updateUI();

            } else {
                console.log("Bad data entered");
                errorMessage.classList.remove("hide");
                return;
            }
        })

        getPix(pixaURL)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response)
            const errorMessage = document.getElementById("error");
            if (response.status == "200") {
                errorMessage.classList.add("hide");
                const image = response.pixaBay.hits[0].webformatURL;
                
                postJournal("/add", { image: image  });

                // Calls to update the site with latest entry
                updateUI();

            } else {
                console.log("Bad data entered");
                errorMessage.classList.remove("hide");
                return;
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to run multiple API requests, then do something once all have finished? You can use Promise.all() for that: https://jsfiddle.net/j5z4a1m0/ If you need the result of promise A to run Promise B, use async / await: https://jsfiddle.net/b2sv0368/

Comment: Hi, that is what am trying to do. Do you have nay suggestion on how to start it.

Comment: I gave you example code for both methods, didn't I?

Comment: yes, you did. Am trying to figure out how to implement it in the code structure I have or do I have to completely change it around>

Comment: If you wrap your code in an async function, you can then probably do `const result = await getGeo(url).then(...).then(...);` but you posted a bunch of code and I'm way too lazy to go through all that.

Comment: Can you take a look at the repo and give me some feedback if you can.
https://github.com/kamara-moses/Capstone-Travel-App

Comment: umm I wish I could pay you but unfortunately am unable to. Thanks for your help>

Comment: Sorry, that was a joke :) I'll take a look at your repo

Comment: Hey, so I moved the API calls into a separate route file and changed it: https://github.com/khrismuc/Capstone-Travel-App/blob/main/src/server/routes/weather.js